# what does val dict = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]().withDefaultValue(0) mean in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections, mutablemap

could anyone explain what below if statement does

```
if (dict.contains(sum-k)) count+= dict(sum-k)
            dict(sum) += 1
```

Actual code:

```
object Solution {
    def subarraySum(nums: Array[Int], k: Int): Int = {
        if (nums isEmpty) return 0
    
    val dict = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
    var count = 0
    
    nums.scanLeft(0)(_+_).foreach { sum => 
        **if (dict.contains(sum-k)) count+= dict(sum-k)
        dict(sum) += 1**
    }
    
    count
}
```

}

Comment: What part of all that you do not understand? or even better what do you understand?

Comment: i didnt the understand (sum-k) as sum hasnt been defined and doesnt seem like it has been used as method.

Comment: sum is defined in the `foreach()` lambda function

Comment: @Divi `sum` is each element on the result of calling `scanLeft` on `nums`, I would recommend you to take a look to the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) and the to the [**Tour of Scala**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html).